# Python Error unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instancemethod' and 'int'

Tags: python, debugging

I am receiving this error when trying to do division

```
   roomRatio = max(self.getRoomWidth(), self.getRoomHeight)/8
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instancemethod' and 'int'
```

`getRoomWidth/Height()` returns integer sizes of the room I am in.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `()`.

```
roomRatio = max(self.getRoomWidth(), self.getRoomHeight())/8
                                                       ^^
```

Note that in Python, you usually don't need `setX()` or `getX()` methods, because you can do this instead:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def getRoomWidth(self):
        ...
    def setRoomWidth(self, width);
        ...
    roomWidth = property(getRoomWidth, setRoomWidth)
```

And to use it,

```
self.width = self.width * 2
```

Comment: Should I just delete this I take it.

Comment: @BumSkeeter you won't be able to now (when it has positively voted answers)... just accept it and move on... :)